# AJAX call log out my account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, warden

I have a Rails 3 app and I am using Warden for authentication.
It works fine but when I try to use AJAX(POST) access one of the controller the application log out my account and ask me to log in again.

Comment: There are several causes, but for a starter you can check whether there is a <%= csrf_meta_tag %> in your application layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the rails [CSRF](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) token validation. There are a few different ways to deal with this:

1. Hacky, dirty shortcut - just make the AJAX call use HTTP GET instead of POST. GET will not look for CSRF token by default
2. Another dirty shortcut - turn off CSRF validation for this particular action in your controller

   ```
   protect_from_forgery :except => :create
   ```
3. Properly implement CSRF token with AJAX calls, there are many guides out there, for example [this one](http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-2-include-csrf-token-with-every-ajax-request/#.UlIzYYZmh8E) or [this one](http://blog.softr.li/post/43146401263/finally-correctly-dealing-with-rails-csrf-protection)

Comment: Definitely would not recommend not using the CSRF tokens, this would be a big security bug..